# Stripe Node - Calculating application fee AFTER discount coupon is used in checkout

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I have a Stripe Checkout Session linked to a connected account. The connected account is subject to a 10% charge from my platform. It works well currently, however now I have added the ability for customers to use coupons in the checkout window, the application fee is being calculated from the total amount *before* the discount is applied.

For example, if I charge €32, the application fee is €3.20. If a discount reduces the charge to €10, the fee *should* be €1. But it is still charging €3.20.

I have a function which calculates the application fee amount, the problem is that this is done when the checkout session is created - this happens before the customer enters the discount.

I can't think of a way around this issue since the session is always created prior to the discount being applied. Any help/suggestions are appreciated!!

```
const calculateApplicationFeeAmount = (total) => total * site.stripeFee;

const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create(
  {
    payment_method_types: ["card"],
    line_items: [
      {
        name: price.name,
        amount: price.amount,
        currency: site.currency,
        quantity: 1,
      },
    ],
    payment_intent_data: {
      application_fee_amount: calculateApplicationFeeAmount(price.amount),
      description: price.name,
    },
    mode: "payment",
    allow_promotion_codes: true,
    success_url: `${config.baseUrl.url}/unlock/session/{CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}`,
    cancel_url: `${config.baseUrl.url}/unlock/${deviceID}`,
    metadata: {
      deviceID: deviceID,
    },
  },
  {
    stripeAccount: site.stripeAccount,
  }
);

return session;
```

Answer (score 3):

The best solution here would probably be to :

1. Use [payment_intent_data.capture_method:manual](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-payment_intent_data-capture_method) when creating the checkout session
2. After receiving the *checkout.session.completed* event, you can capture the PaymentIntent by including the [application_fee_amount](https://docs.stripe.com/api/charges/capture#capture_charge-application_fee_amount) https://docs.stripe.com/api/charges/capture#capture_charge-application_fee_amount

The limitation is that not all payment methods support manual capture.

Alternatively, you could also refund the application fee later : https://stripe.com/docs/api/fee_refunds/create

Comment: Thank you Alex. That sounds like it should do the job! I’ll give that a go and post my feedback later 

Comment: So I have tried to update the intent, however I receive the following error message: "StripeInvalidRequestError: Some of the parameters you provided (application_fee_amount) cannot be used when modifying a PaymentIntent that was created by Checkout. You can try again without those parameters."

Comment: Chatted with Stripe support. Apparently this is a limitation when using Connect + Checkout. In my opinion it makes the redemption of coupons redundant for anyone using Connect + Checkout.